# Tried to change the theme now I messed it up

Tags: html, css, shopify

I've tried to add the code in `assets/theme.scss`. liquid but now my website is all messed up. I've deleted the code tried to roll back but it's still the same.

```
 Jumpstart Theme
 Table of contents:
  1. BASICS
    1.1. Reset
    1.2. Variables
    1.3. Mixins
    1.4. Grid
    1.5. Helper classes
    1.6. Typography
  2. STRUCTURE
    2.1. General
    2.2. Header
    2.3. Navigation
    2.4. Footer
    2.5. Objects
    2.6. Forms
    2.7  Blank states
  3. HOME PAGE
    3.1. General
    3.2. Crowdfunding
    3.3. Hero
    3.4. Image feature content
    3.5. Slideshow
    3.6. Page
    3.7. FAQ
    3.8. Features
    3.9. Clients
    3.10. Gallery
    3.11. Newsletter
    3.12. Feature collection
    3.13. Map
    3.14. Rich text
  4. TEMPLATES
    4.1. Blog
    4.2. Collections
    4.3. Cart
    4.4. Password
    4.5. Customer
    4.6. Captcha
  5. MAGNIFIC POPUP
```

it looks like there is an error in your theme.

> Try assets/theme.scss.liquid in the template editor to fix the error
>   below:
>
> Invalid CSS after "...le of contents:": expected pseudoclass or
>   pseudoelement, was "1. BASICS" at 2

Comment: possibly missing a semicolon after you added some property in your css

Comment: Hello, You should not try to put text or html inside an scss file...

Comment: What is the content you show? Is that what you added?

Comment: https://ibb.co/B6gcvf3

Answer (score 0):

Before the first rule (Jumpstart Theme) add `/*` again

Comment: Thank you so much you are life saver!

Comment: No problem... Don't forget to come back one day and accept the answer ;)